# Convergence of Dirichlet series

Tags: complex-analysis, dirichlet-series

Let $\alpha$ be a Dirichlet series such that $\alpha(s)$ converges for all real numbers $s>0$. Suppose that $\lim_{s\downarrow0}\alpha(s)$ exists. How to prove that $\alpha(0)$ converges?

I know this is true if and only if $\alpha(s)$ converges uniformly in $(0,1)$.

The abscissa of convergence is at most $0$. If $\sigma_c<0$, then $\alpha(0)$ converges. But if $\sigma_c=0$, then $0$ lies on the line of convergence so it is not sure whether $\alpha(0)$ converges.

Comment: Duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/137430/convergence-of-dirichlet-series-at-the-boundary

Comment: That's why proving the prime number theorem isn't so easy. Search about the [Tauberian theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%E2%80%93Ikehara_theorem). And the iff "converges uniformly on $(0,1)$" is not true

Comment: @reuns If there is uniformly convergence, it is true that $\alpha(0)$ converges by the Moore-Osgood theorem, and if $\alpha(0)$ converges, then it is a well-known fact that $\alpha(s)$ converges on $(0,1)$. So why is this iff statement not true?

Comment: @Riemann That $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges implies (partial summation) that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}$ converges uniformly for $\Re(s) \ge \epsilon$ and on rays $|s| \ge  0, \text{arg}(s) \in [-\epsilon,\epsilon]$. Conversely if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}$ converges uniformly on $|s| >  0, \text{arg}(s) \in [-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ then it converges uniformly on $|s| \ge  0, \text{arg}(s) \in [-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ by continuity of $\sum_{n=N}^M a_n n^{-s}$.

Comment: If one takes $\epsilon=0$, then $\arg(s)\in[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ implies $s\in\mathbb R_{\geq0}$. So, if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nn^{-s}$ converges uniformly on $(0,\infty)$. Conversely, if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nn^{-s}$ converges uniformly on $(0,\infty)$, then it converges uniformly on $ \[0,\infty\)$, so it converges for $s=0$. So, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nn^{-s}$ converges uniformly on $(0,\infty)$ if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges.

Comment: @Riemann Taking $\epsilon=0$ is nearly never a valid step...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is mentioned in an answer linked by Dap in a comment, the result you are trying to prove is false. For this, consider the series
$$\alpha(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{s+1+i}}=\zeta(s+1+i).$$
The series converges absolutely for $s>0$ (in fact, for all $s$ with $\operatorname{Re}(s)>0$), but it diverges at $s=0$. Here is an elementary proof.

Consider the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_n^{n+1}\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^{1+i}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_1^n\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^{1+i}}.$$
For $n\leq x\leq n+1$ we have
$$\left|\frac{1}{x^{1+i}}-\frac{1}{n^{1+i}}\right|=\left|1+i\right|\left|\int_n^x\frac{\mathrm dt}{t^{2+i}}\right|\leq 2\int_n^x\frac{\mathrm dt}{t^2}\leq 2\int_n^{n+1}\frac{\mathrm dt}{n^2}=\frac{2}{n^2},$$
hence
$$\left|\int_n^{n+1}\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^{1+i}}-\frac{1}{n^{1+i}}\right|=\left|\int_n^{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{x^{1+i}}-\frac{1}{n^{1+i}}\right)\mathrm dx\right|\leq\int_n^{n+1}\left|\frac{1}{x^{1+i}}-\frac{1}{n^{1+i}}\right|\mathrm dx\leq\frac{2}{n^2}.$$

Since the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-2}$ converges, this gives that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-(1+i)}$ converges iff the series I've defined above does. But we have
$$\int_1^n\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^{1+i}}=\frac{1}{-i}\left(\frac{1}{n^i}-1\right)=\frac{1}{-i}\left(e^{-i\log n}-1\right)$$
which does not converge as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Therefore the series defining $\alpha(0)$ does not converge.